# NullPointerException in Intent.getIntent().getExtras()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

- I am using Intent to pass names(ArrayList) from one activity to another.
- I called the getIntent() method in the second activity's onCreate() method.
- want to use passed names(ArrayList) inside my own functions but it is **out of scope**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Intent intent = getIntent();
   
           Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
           ArrayList<String> namesList = bundle.getStringArrayList("names");
   }
```

Want to use names in this:

```
    public class game_main extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView playerNameHolder;
        .........................
        .........................
        .........................
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        ArrayList<String> namesList = bundle.getStringArrayList("names");
        ........................
        ........................
        ........................
        public void gameReset(View view) {
        ........................
        ........................
        TextView playerNameHolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.turn_status);
        playerNameHolder.setText(namesList.get(0) + "'s turn");
        }
    }
```

namesList.get(0) is out of scope when Bundle line code is not included, but when included it gives NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference**

Answer (score 1):

Do not call methods on `AppCompatActivity` (or superclasses) from field initializers, such as you are doing with `Intent intent = getIntent();` in your second code snippet.

You need to combine your two approaches: putting `namesList` as a field and initializing it in `onCreate()`:

```java
public class game_main extends AppCompatActivity {
   ArrayList<String> namesList;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Intent intent = getIntent();
   
           Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
           
           namesList = bundle.getStringArrayList("names");
   }
}
```